# When is work done on a body positive and negative, relative to the angle?

Tags: work

I want to get some facts clear about work done with respect to the angle. Work done is the dot product between force applied and the displacement covered (W=Fcos(theta) d). We know that the work done will be 0 if the angle is 90,270,450... Now to the main point. The trigonometric ratio is cosine. It's positive in the 1st and 4th quadrant, and then it's also an even function. So, if I'm not wrong, work done should be positive if angle is between 0 and 90 degree, 270 to 450 degree, and in negative angle it should be 0 to -90, and -270 to -450 and so on, and is maximum on 0 and 360. As for negative work done, it should be 90 to 270, 450 to 630 and so on, and the maximum negative value should be on 180,540 and so on. Am I correct? If not, then please elaborate.

Comment: It is easier to see that the work done by *F* on an object is positive if the *F* has some component along the movement of the particle.  This happens when the F is within 90 degrees on either side of the  particle's direction. Also notice $\cos(\theta) = \cos(-\theta)$.

Comment: It would be unusual to express angles larger than $\pm 180$ degrees, since we aren't expressing how far something *has* rotated, but how far you'd have to rotate one thing for it to be parallel with something else.

Answer (score 2):

Just draw the vectors (the displacement vector and the force vector).

- Is the angle between them *below* 90 degrees, then work done is positive.
- Is it *larger* than 90 degrees, then negative.

The mathematical dot product takes care of this sign:

$$W=\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf d.$$

Essentially, a dot product multiplies together the parallel (sign-valued) components of the vectors. That is what the formula $$W=d F\cos(\theta)$$ takes care of, because the parallel component of, say, the force vector is $F_\parallel=F\cos(\theta)$. If the component of one vector along the other vector is in the same direction, then the cosine term becomes positive.

So, mathematically, all you need to look at is when the cosine function is positive. And remember that we are only looking at the angle *between* the vectors, so we are only considering up to 180 degrees.

Your description is a bit hard to follow, but this is essentially all there is to it.

Comment: Ok so what you're saying is that the angle is only gonna be between 0-180 b/c the vectors are usually only perpendicular or parallel. That is why angle more than 90 will give negative work done because in this case we only consider the angle till 180 degree. Is that correct?

Comment: @Asad "*the vectors are usually only perpendicular or parallel*" No, there is no need to assume that vectors typically are either perpendicular or parallel. I'm not sure what you mean by this, because when this is the case then the angle consideration is often trivial. Regarding the angle, keep in mind that you cannot angle two vectors at more than 180 degrees from one another. If it becomes 181 degrees then we flip the measurement to the other side, and then the angle to plug into the formula would instead be 179 degrees.